# can dissolving be endothermic process

Tags: endocrinology

can dissolving be endothermic process. I have a container with glucose(solid state) and added water and found the container getting colder. was wondering there is no reaction(just a physical process) and why would it absorb heat.

Comment: Yes, it can. This a question for [chemistry.se].

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question in general is yes.
There are many salts and compounds that are endothermic - they cool the solution when they dissolve.  It also turns out that glucose is endothermic when it dissolves [if this sheet i found is to be believed](http://webserver.dmt.upm.es/~isidoro/dat1/Heat%20of%20solution%20data.pdf).  Its not a strong effect but you made an accurate observation!

Endothermic salts can be quite cold.  This is how home ice cream makers often work in fact - rock salt dissolves into the ice and makes it even colder than it started out to be. I believe that is how ice cream was made before refrigeration and ice storage arrived in the 19th century.

Comment: Welcome back! How have you been? How's the company going?

Comment: thanks Alice!  very well - raising funds for a new startup...